# Error logging Spark model with mlflow to databricks registry, via databricks-connect

Tags: python, databricks, mlflow, databricks-connect

I'm trying to log a trained spark model on mlflow using databricks-connect. I want this model to be logged in the Databricks registry. For now, my code looks like this:

```py
mlflow.set_tracking_uri("databricks")
mlflow.set_experiment("/Users/xxxxx/experiment_name")

with mlflow.start_run(run_name="my_run") as _:
    mlflow.spark.log_model(my_spark_model, "my_model")
```

When it runs the log_model line, execution breaks with the following stack trace:

> 22/07/21 11:05:03 WARN ProtoSerializer: Failed to deserialize remote exception
> java.io.InvalidClassException: failed to read class descriptor
> at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.util.ProtoSerializer.$anonfun$deserializeObject$1(ProtoSerializer.scala:6618)
> at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.util.ProtoSerializer.deserializeObject(ProtoSerializer.scala:6603)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.util.ProtoSerializer.deserializeException(ProtoSerializer.scala:6634)
> at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner.executeRPC(SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner.scala:188)
> at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner.$anonfun$execute0$1(SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner.scala:121)
> at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
> at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner.withRetry(SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner.scala:135)
> at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner.execute0(SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner.scala:113)
> at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner.scala:86)
> at com.databricks.spark.util.Log4jUsageLogger.recordOperation(UsageLogger.scala:247)
> at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogger.scala:429)
> at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogger.scala:408)
> at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRPCClientStub.recordOperation(SparkServiceRPCClientStub.scala:58)
> at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner.execute(SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner.scala:78)
> at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner.execute$(SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner.scala:67)
> at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRPCClientStub.execute(SparkServiceRPCClientStub.scala:58)
> at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRPCClientStub.fileSystemOperation(SparkServiceRPCClientStub.scala:297)
> at com.databricks.service.FSClient.send(FSClient.scala:51)
> at com.databricks.service.FSClient.getFileStatus(FSClient.scala:181)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1426)
> at org.apache.spark.ml.util.FileSystemOverwrite.handleOverwrite(ReadWrite.scala:675)
> at org.apache.spark.ml.util.MLWriter.save(ReadWrite.scala:167)
> at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$PipelineModelWriter.super$save(Pipeline.scala:344)
> at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$PipelineModelWriter.$anonfun$save$4(Pipeline.scala:344)
> at org.apache.spark.ml.MLEvents.withSaveInstanceEvent(events.scala:175)
> at org.apache.spark.ml.MLEvents.withSaveInstanceEvent$(events.scala:170)
> at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation.withSaveInstanceEvent(Instrumentation.scala:43)
> at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$PipelineModelWriter.$anonfun$save$3(Pipeline.scala:344)
> at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$PipelineModelWriter.$anonfun$save$3$adapted(Pipeline.scala:344)
> at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$.$anonfun$instrumented$1(Instrumentation.scala:284)
> at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
> at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$.instrumented(Instrumentation.scala:284)
> at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$PipelineModelWriter.save(Pipeline.scala:344)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
> at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
> at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
> at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
> at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.common.InvalidMountException
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
> at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:242)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.util.SparkServiceObjectInputStream.readResolveClassDescriptor(SparkServiceObjectInputStream.scala:60)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.util.SparkServiceObjectInputStream.readClassDescriptor(SparkServiceObjectInputStream.scala:55)
> ... 51 more
> **22/07/21 11:05:03 ERROR Instrumentation: com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRemoteException: com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.common.InvalidMountException: Error while using path /databricks/mlflow-tracking/000000000000000/0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a/artifacts\experiment_name/sparkml for resolving path '/000000000000000/0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a/artifacts\experiment_name/sparkml' within mount at '/databricks/mlflow-tracking'.> **

> <...>>

> **Caused by: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: unsupported-access-mechanism-for-path--use-mlflow-client**
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2660)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
> at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2Factory.createFileSystem(DatabricksFileSystemV2Factory.scala:124)
> at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.filesystem.MountEntryResolver.$anonfun$resolve$1(MountEntryResolver.scala:67)
> at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$recordOperation$1(UsageLogging.scala:395)
> at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.executeThunkAndCaptureResultTags$1(UsageLogging.scala:484)
> at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$recordOperationWithResultTags$4(UsageLogging.scala:504)
> at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:266)
> at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
> at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:261)
> at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:258)
> at com.databricks.common.util.locks.LoggedLock$.withAttributionContext(LoggedLock.scala:73)
> at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:305)
> at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:297)
> at com.databricks.common.util.locks.LoggedLock$.withAttributionTags(LoggedLock.scala:73)
> at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperationWithResultTags(UsageLogging.scala:479)
> at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperationWithResultTags$(UsageLogging.scala:404)
> at com.databricks.common.util.locks.LoggedLock$.recordOperationWithResultTags(LoggedLock.scala:73)
> at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogging.scala:395)
> at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogging.scala:367)
> at com.databricks.common.util.locks.LoggedLock$.recordOperation(LoggedLock.scala:73)
> at com.databricks.common.util.locks.LoggedLock$.withLock(LoggedLock.scala:120)
> at com.databricks.common.util.locks.PerKeyLock.withLock(PerKeyLock.scala:36)
> at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.filesystem.MountEntryResolver.resolve(MountEntryResolver.scala:64)>

> <...>
> _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _>

> answer = 'xro1535'
> gateway_client = <py4j.java_gateway.GatewayClient object at 0x0000023716B5BE20>
> target_id = 'o1532', name = 'copyToLocalFile'>
>
> ```
> def get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id=None, name=None):
>     """Converts an answer received from the Java gateway into a Python object.
>
>     For example, string representation of integers are converted to Python
>     integer, string representation of objects are converted to JavaObject
>     instances, etc.
>
>     :param answer: the string returned by the Java gateway
>     :param gateway_client: the gateway client used to communicate with the Java
>         Gateway. Only necessary if the answer is a reference (e.g., object,
>         list, map)
>     :param target_id: the name of the object from which the answer comes from
>         (e.g., *object1* in `object1.hello()`). Optional.
>     :param name: the name of the member from which the answer comes from
>         (e.g., *hello* in `object1.hello()`). Optional.
>     """
>     if is_error(answer)[0]:
>         if len(answer) > 1:
>             type = answer[1]
>             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
>             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
>                raise Py4JJavaError(
>                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
>                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
> ```
>
> E                   py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1532.copyToLocalFile.
> E                   : **java.io.IOException: (null) entry in command string: null chmod 0644 C:\Users\itscarlayall\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpalmxdo16\model\sparkml\metadata_SUCCESS**
> E                       at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:773)
> E                       at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:869)
> E                       at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:852)
> E                       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:733)
> E                       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.(RawLocalFileSystem.java:225)
> E                       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
> E                       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
> E                       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
> E                       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! I needed to install winutils. Apparently, even though databricks-connect sends the execution to the remote databricks, there are still some local operations mlflow needs to save a spark model ‍♀️